# How to make a button for a photo when I click and record video when I hold it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm trying to make only one button for photos and video recording:

- when I press it once it will take a picture
- when I hold it, after a while the video is recording

Button in View:

```
<TouchableOpacity
    onPressIn={() => onPressInButton()}
    onPressOut={() => onPressOutButton()}
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Code for button:

```
const insidePressInButton = async () => {
    if (!pressOut) {
        setRecordingVideo(true)
        console.log('START RECORDING VIDEO')
    }
    else {
        await takePicture()
        console.log('NOT STARTED RECORDING -> PICTURE')
    }
}

let pressOut = false
const onPressInButton = async () => {
    pressOut = false
    setTimeout(() => {
        insidePressInButton()
    }, 1)
}

const onPressOutButton = async () => {
    pressOut = true
    if (recordingVideo) {
        setRecordingVideo(false)
        console.log('STOP RECORDING VIDEO')
    }
}
```

In `setTimeout()` I set the time to only `1` (very little) and the wait is long (I think this is React's problem with re-rendering)

Theoretically, this solution works, but I have one **big problem**

**When I click once and want a picture, I have to wait more than a second**

He would like to do so that the picture is taken immediately and when I hold the button for a moment and keep holding it is recording the video

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `onLongPress`([doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback.html#onlongpress)) for video record and set delay via `delayLongPress` ([doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback.html#delaylongpress)). As a result if you will press less than 200, it's picture in other case is video recording

```js
<TouchableOpacity
    onPress={...}
    onLongPress={...}
    delayLongPress={200}
</TouchableOpacity>
```